# How can I remotely access Jupyter from an azure VM?

Tags: linux, python, azure, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to get Jupyter notebook to run on an Azure VM, and it's failing miserably.  I first created a [linux virtual machine](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/machinelearning/2016/04/13/announcing-the-availability-of-the-linux-data-science-virtual-machine/), then I followed [these instructions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-jupyter-notebook/) exactly--I created an inbound rule in the network settings for the different ports I tried (8888, 10000, 9999 was already there but was already in use when I tried it), installed anaconda3, and everything else in the tutorial exactly.  One thing that seems strange is every time I execute the command:

```
/anaconda3/bin/python -c "import IPython;print(IPython.lib.passwd())"
```

It gives me a different sha key.  Shouldn't it be the same if I'm giving it the same password every time?

Then when I run

/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook

it gives the output:

```
[I 21:17:19.474 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /dsvm/Notebooks
[I 21:17:19.474 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 21:17:19.474 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: https://[all ip addresses on your system]:10000/
[I 21:17:19.474 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

The thing that seems wrong is the 'all ip addresses on your system' part; shouldn't that be different?  If I do

```
curl -k https://localhost:10000
```

it works fine, but it won't open in either firefox or chrome on my local computer.

Answer (score 0):

1) It is not incorrect. Your application is running on all IPs assigned to the VM

```
all ip addresses on your system
```

2) Are you accessing notebook using 'https://localhost:10000' from your local machine? You will have to access it using public IP address

3) If you are trying to access it using public IP, can you please let us know what exactly you are seeing in the browser? You might try to access it using 'http' not https